# Insert multiple result JSON data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to insert the JSON data into MySQL database in the very obvious way as given an example in the picture. Picture shows the same data, but outputed in CSV format and that's how exactly I want it to be in MySQL.

I have prepared the database and the query for inserting, however I can't figure out the code to find right array key or value

```
...  prepared query
// INSERT INTO `utakmice`(`utakmica_name`, `utakmica_kladionica_name`, `utakmica_kladionica_kvota1`, `utakmica_kladionica_kvotax`, `utakmica_kladionica_kvota2`, `utakmica_kladionica_kvota3plus`, `utakmica_kladionica_kvota0_2`) VALUES ([value], [value], [value], [value], [value], [value], [value])

$json_array = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($json_array as $key => $arrays){

    foreach($arrays as $array){
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
        }
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

[See picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZEfl.png)

**JSON:**

```
{
 "utakmica": [
  {
   "name": "Kimarones de Sonora-Klub Selaja",
   "kladionica": [
    {
     "name": "Admiral Bet",
     "kvota1": "2.05",
     "kvotax": "3.00",
     "kvota2": "3.70",
     "kvota3plus": "2.60"
    },
    {
     "name": "Balkan Bet",
     "kvota1": "2.15",
     "kvotax": "2.80",
     "kvota2": "3.65",
     "kvota0_2": "1.42",
     "kvota3plus": "2.65"
    },
    {
     "name": "BetOle",
     "kvota1": "2.02",
     "kvotax": "2.93",
     "kvota2": "3.95",
     "kvota0_2": "1.40",
     "kvota3plus": "2.72"
    },
    {
     "name": "Lob",
     "kvota1": "2.05",
     "kvotax": "2.95",
     "kvota2": "3.80",
     "kvota0_2": "1.41",
     "kvota3plus": "2.60"
    },
    {
     "name": "MaxBet",
     "kvota1": "2.20",
     "kvotax": "2.90",
     "kvota2": "3.45",
     "kvota0_2": "1.45",
     "kvota3plus": "2.50"
    },
    {
     "name": "Meridian",
     "kvota1": "2.17",
     "kvotax": "2.85",
     "kvota2": "3.60",
     "kvota0_2": "1.45",
     "kvota3plus": "2.65"
    },
    {
     "name": "MerkurXtip",
     "kvota1": "2.20",
     "kvotax": "2.75",
     "kvota2": "3.40",
     "kvota0_2": "1.43",
     "kvota3plus": "2.50"
    },
    {
     "name": "Mozzart",
     "kvota1": "2.15",
     "kvotax": "3.00",
     "kvota2": "3.50",
     "kvota0_2": "1.47",
     "kvota3plus": "2.50"
    },
    {
     "name": "Oktagonbet",
     "kvota1": "2.30",
     "kvotax": "2.80",
     "kvota2": "3.30",
     "kvota0_2": "1.40",
     "kvota3plus": "2.70"
    },
    {
     "name": "Olimp",
     "kvota1": "2.15",
     "kvotax": "2.90",
     "kvota2": "3.45",
     "kvota0_2": "1.50",
     "kvota3plus": "2.30"
    },
    {
     "name": "Taš-Bet",
     "kvota1": "2.20",
     "kvotax": "2.80",
     "kvota2": "3.40",
     "kvota0_2": "1.47",
     "kvota3plus": "2.60"
    },
    {
     "name": "Top Bet",
     "kvota1": "2.30",
     "kvotax": "2.85",
     "kvota2": "3.10",
     "kvota0_2": "1.45",
     "kvota3plus": "2.55"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Al Naser-Al Šabab Kuvajt",
   "kladionica": [
    {
     "name": "Admiral Bet",
     "kvota1": "1.83",
     "kvota2": "4.10",
     "kvota0_2": "1.72",
     "kvota3plus": "2.00"
    },
    {
     "name": "Balkan Bet",
     "kvota1": "1.77",
     "kvotax": "3.25",
     "kvota2": "4.00",
     "kvota0_2": "1.65",
     "kvota3plus": "2.00"
    },
    {
     "name": "Lob",
     "kvota1": "1.89",
     "kvotax": "2.95",
     "kvota2": "4.15",
     "kvota0_2": "1.62",
     "kvota3plus": "2.08"
    },
    {
     "name": "MaxBet",
     "kvota1": "1.83",
     "kvotax": "3.15",
     "kvota2": "4.10",
     "kvota0_2": "1.70",
     "kvota3plus": "1.95"
    },
    {
     "name": "Meridian",
     "kvota1": "1.82",
     "kvotax": "3.40",
     "kvota2": "4.00",
     "kvota0_2": "1.71",
     "kvota3plus": "2.02"
    },
    {
     "name": "Mozzart",
     "kvota1": "1.92",
     "kvotax": "3.35",
     "kvota2": "3.80",
     "kvota0_2": "1.72",
     "kvota3plus": "2.00"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Al Rustak-Al Sib",
   "kladionica": [
    {
     "name": "Admiral Bet",
     "kvota1": "3.70",
     "kvota2": "1.95",
     "kvota0_2": "1.48",
     "kvota3plus": "2.35"
    },
    {
     "name": "Lob",
     "kvota1": "3.80",
     "kvotax": "3.10",
     "kvota2": "2.08",
     "kvota0_2": "1.47",
     "kvota3plus": "2.45"
    },
    {
     "name": "MaxBet",
     "kvota1": "3.55",
     "kvotax": "3.10",
     "kvota2": "1.88",
     "kvota0_2": "1.48",
     "kvota3plus": "2.35"
    },
    {
     "name": "Meridian",
     "kvota1": "3.85",
     "kvotax": "3.05",
     "kvota2": "1.98",
     "kvota0_2": "1.48",
     "kvota3plus": "2.41"
    },
    {
     "name": "Mozzart",
     "kvota1": "4.00",
     "kvotax": "3.05",
     "kvota2": "2.00",
     "kvota0_2": "1.47",
     "kvota3plus": "2.50"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "El Šarkeja-Talaea El Džaiš",
   "kladionica": [
    {
     "name": "Admiral Bet",
     "kvota1": "3.60",
     "kvota2": "2.15",
     "kvota0_2": "1.53",
     "kvota3plus": "2.45"
    },
    {
     "name": "Balkan Bet",
     "kvota1": "3.50",
     "kvotax": "2.80",
     "kvota2": "2.20",
     "kvota0_2": "1.47",
     "kvota3plus": "2.50"
    },
    {
     "name": "BetOle",
     "kvota1": "3.60",
     "kvotax": "2.85",
     "kvota2": "2.15",
     "kvota0_2": "1.50",
     "kvota3plus": "2.43"
    },
    {
     "name": "Lob",
     "kvota1": "3.50",
     "kvotax": "2.85",
     "kvota2": "2.12",
     "kvota0_2": "1.47",
     "kvota3plus": "2.38"
    },
    {
     "name": "MaxBet",
     "kvota1": "3.55",
     "kvotax": "2.95",
     "kvota2": "2.15",
     "kvota0_2": "1.50",
     "kvota3plus": "2.40"
    },
    {
     "name": "Meridian",
     "kvota1": "3.95",
     "kvotax": "2.90",
     "kvota2": "2.12",
     "kvota0_2": "1.49",
     "kvota3plus": "2.60"
    },
    {
     "name": "MerkurXtip",
     "kvota1": "3.65",
     "kvotax": "2.72",
     "kvota2": "2.23",
     "kvota0_2": "1.48",
     "kvota3plus": "2.40"
    },
    {
     "name": "Mozzart",
     "kvota1": "3.60",
     "kvotax": "2.95",
     "kvota2": "2.15",
     "kvota0_2": "1.41",
     "kvota3plus": "2.70"
    },
    {
     "name": "Oktagonbet",
     "kvota1": "3.60",
     "kvotax": "2.80",
     "kvota2": "2.18",
     "kvota0_2": "1.50",
     "kvota3plus": "2.40"
    },
    {
     "name": "Olimp",
     "kvota1": "3.80",
     "kvotax": "2.95",
     "kvota2": "2.10",
     "kvota0_2": "1.45",
     "kvota3plus": "2.50"
    },
    {
     "name": "Taš-Bet",
     "kvota1": "3.50",
     "kvotax": "2.90",
     "kvota2": "2.15",
     "kvota0_2": "1.50",
     "kvota3plus": "2.45"
    },
    {
     "name": "Top Bet",
     "kvota1": "3.00",
     "kvotax": "3.10",
     "kvota2": "2.20",
     "kvota0_2": "1.50",
     "kvota3plus": "2.40"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

MySQL create table looks like such;

```
CREATE TABLE `utakmice` (
  `utakmica_name` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `utakmica_kladionica_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `utakmica_kladionica_kvota1` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `utakmica_kladionica_kvotax` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `utakmica_kladionica_kvota2` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `utakmica_kladionica_kvota3plus` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `utakmica_kladionica_kvota0_2` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Current code

```
  $parsehub = new Parsehub($api_key);
    $data =  $parsehub->getLastReadyRunData($project_token);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO utakmice
    SELECT jsontable1.utakmica_name, 
           jsontable2.*
    FROM ( SELECT ? AS source_JSON ) AS data_source
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(data_source.source_JSON,
                          '$.utakmica[*]' 
                          COLUMNS ( utakmica_name VARCHAR(64) PATH '$.name' ERROR ON EMPTY,
                                    kladionica JSON PATH '$.kladionica' ERROR ON EMPTY
                                   )
                          ) jsontable1
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(jsontable1.kladionica,
                          '$[*]'
                          COLUMNS ( utakmica_kladionica_name VARCHAR(64) PATH '$.name' ERROR ON EMPTY,
                                    utakmica_kladionica_kvota1 DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvota1' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY,
                                    utakmica_kladionica_kvotax DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvotax' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY, 
                                    utakmica_kladionica_kvota2 DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvota2' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY, 
                                    utakmica_kladionica_kvota3plus DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvota3plus' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY, 
                                    utakmica_kladionica_kvota0_2 DECIMAL(10,2) PATH  '$.kvota0_2' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY
                                   )
                          ) jsontable2;");

       $stmt->bind_param("s", $data);
       $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO utakmice
SELECT jsontable1.utakmica_name, 
       jsontable2.*
FROM ( SELECT @input AS source_JSON ) AS data_source
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(data_source.source_JSON,
                      '$.utakmica[*]' 
                      COLUMNS ( utakmica_name VARCHAR(64) PATH '$.name' ERROR ON EMPTY,
                                kladionica JSON PATH '$.kladionica' ERROR ON EMPTY
                               )
                      ) jsontable1
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(jsontable1.kladionica,
                      '$[*]'
                      COLUMNS ( utakmica_kladionica_name VARCHAR(64) PATH '$.name' ERROR ON EMPTY,
                                utakmica_kladionica_kvota1 DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvota1' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY,
                                utakmica_kladionica_kvotax DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvotax' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY, 
                                utakmica_kladionica_kvota2 DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvota2' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY, 
                                utakmica_kladionica_kvota3plus DECIMAL(10,2) PATH '$.kvota3plus' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY, 
                                utakmica_kladionica_kvota0_2 DECIMAL(10,2) PATH  '$.kvota0_2' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY
                               )
                      ) jsontable2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8dd034010d9c6a65f3027d8e30eba6b

PS. The datatypes changed from `DECIMAL(10,0)` to `DECIMAL(10,2)` because the values contains 2 decimal digits.

PPS. The subquery `data_source` is added for a case when you want to provide a rowset of JSON values. If you'll provide one JSON only then you may remove this subquery and use `.. FROM JSON_TABLE(@input, ..` (see last SELECT in the fiddle).

Comment: I think the `JSON_TABLE` voodoo could use a bit more explanation for researchers that are new to this technique, but I like this answer enough to uv it.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think writing a tutorial on using a function doesn't make sense. In Reference Manual, all this is written quite well and in detail. And if the OP has any questions, then he can ask them, and I will explain what is unclear.

Comment: Okay, that's your prerogative.  This is not a code-only answer, so I am happy. When I post a regex answer, I typically try to explain the pattern so that readers who are not fluent in regex can try to grasp what I've created.  I understand what you are doing with `$.utakmica[*]` and `$[*]`, I'm just trying to be mindful of people that don't follow the basic technique/syntax.  Also, my stance is: the better explained this answer is, the more likely it will be a good page to close a future duplicate question.

Comment: @mickmackusa When you explain what your regex performs precisely then you assume that OP have some base knowledge about the regex syntax and usage. In this case I do not see what can be unclear if OP have base knowledge about JSON_TABLE function and JSON paths syntax. SQL language is self-descriptive, so the query text is self-explanation at the same time. I understand that some points can be unclear, and I wait for precise questions. If somebody (maybe OP) will ask then I, of course, will explain in details. Maybe, even I'll update the answer with additional question and my explanation.

Comment: The answer seems interesting, however I don't understand how to use it. Where should I declare the json file in the query? I've tried replacing `FROM ( SELECT @input` to `FROM ( SELECT '$data'`, but the data isn't inserting.

2) Do I need to use these loops from my code?

Comment: @BenjaminA.Kovacevic *Where should I declare the json file in the query?* File, not value? The data must be taken from the file on disk? *Do I need to use these loops from my code?* If you need to process a lot of separate JSONs - yes, otherwise no. *I've tried replacing FROM ( SELECT \@input to FROM ( SELECT '$data', but the data isn't inserting.* 1) Use prepared statements, not direct value insertion. 2) Check your JSON, maybe it contains some chars which needs in quoting.

Comment: The JSON is located on a webpage and is continuously updating, and for sake of not downloading it every time, I have got it in variable $data. The echo result of it would be the same as json that I posted. 

I understand the looping part that you're saying, but honestly not the prepared statements. 

I have updated question with current code at the bottom.

Comment: @BenjaminA.Kovacevic *I understand the looping part that you're saying, but honestly not the prepared statements.* https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php So you use `.. FROM ( SELECT ? AS source_JSON ) AS data_source ..`, then `$mysqli->prepare` for prepare the query, `$stmt->bind_param` for to bind the parameter value, and finally `$stmt->execute()` for to obtain the result. If you need to process a lot of JSONs then you prepare the query once then bind and execute in cycle (without connection closing, of course).

Comment: I only have one JSON file.
I updated the code (in a question too) and getting error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /var/www/html/arbitage-betting2/test.php:39 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/arbitage-betting2/test.php on line 39

I'm helpless. Thank you for going this far

Comment: I cannot help you with Php - I don't use it.

Comment: People say "It sounds like you may have an error in the query being used in the prepare statement just prior to this. Instead of prepare returning a MySQLi statement object to your variable, you are being returned a bool false. That is then causing the fatal error you see here. Take a look at your SQL statement and see if you have some sort of an error in your syntax"

Could you check it and edit to one json file? That would help
I'm really not famiiar with subqueries and i'm afraid of deleting wrong things

Comment: The query is correct, and the fiddle proves this. So your problem is not query problem. All another execution steps are out of my business.

Comment: I managed to do it and your query did the trick. I'm very grateful.

Comment: I have added 2 more fields to json, I'm trying to correct the query for 2 hours already..
could you help?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31126aaac9c6539011cb3353787377d1